# How to use `preg_replace` to remove repeated chars with spaces around

Tags: php, regex

I have multiple strings and I need to remove repeated chars. For example: the string `here abbbbbc x` should become `here abc x` or the string `test jjka` should become `test jka`.

After studying, I came up with the code below which works fine (it uses PHP but you can use any language):

```
echo preg_replace("/([a-z])\\1+/","$1","test ajjjo new");
```

The code above will output `test ajo new` which is great!

My problem now, is that I need to only replace the repeated chars if they are inside a word or at the beggining of end of the word. For example: I need the string `here bbb cca` to become `here bbb ca` and the string `test hjjjja ppp` to become `test hja ppp`. I tried negating the   (space) and `^` and `$` but it all becomes a mess pretty fast.

How would you recommend me?

Comment: What is "a word"? `jjka`, `hjjjja`, and `bbb` all don't seem like words to be but for some reason `bbb` is not being replaced.

Comment: I would think word boundaries could be used but question isn't clear to me so that may be wrong

Comment: @CarySwoveland this would not reduce "accc" for example

Comment: @DuesserBaest, thanks for that. Actually it was a misunderstanding of the question rather than an oversight. I wasn't sure if "of" was a typo or part of an awkward phrasing and are no examples to clarify it. Upon reflection I think you are correct. Please see my revised regex below.

Comment: You can replace matches of the regular expression `(?<!\S)([a-z])\1*(?!\S)\K|([a-z])(?=\2)` with empty strings. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DABJsI/1). The backslashes may need to be doubled. Note that zero-width matches that end after `\K` may be replaced with empty strings, thereby having no effect. Hover the cursor over each part of the regex at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Comment: Samuel, I suggest you change the title to something like, "How to remove repeated characters from a word except when the word contains only one unique character". Speaking of "inside a word", "beginning of word" and "end of word" (note the typo) is unnecessary and confusing if you state the single exception in the suggested title. I suggest you add examples such as `"baa"`, `"baca"` and `"cddedffdd"`. `"baca"` is intended to show that you mean repeated, *contiguous* characters.

Comment: Is `beggining of end of the word` meant to be `beginning or end of the word`?  I don't find this [mcve] to be very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace each match of the regular expression

```
(?<!\S)([a-z])\1*(?!\S)\K|([a-z])\2*(?=\2)
```

with an empty string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pAg19K/1)

Though I don't know PHP I gather that some or all of the backslashes may need to be doubled.

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<!\S)  # negative lookbehind asserts that the following character is not
         # preceded by a character other than a whitespace.
([a-z])  # match a lowercase letter and save it to capture group 1
\1*      # match zero of more instances of the character in capture group 1
(?!\S)   # negative lookahead asserts that the following character is not a
         # character other than a whitespace.
\K       # reset the start of the match and discard all previously-consumed
         # characters
|        # or
([a-z])  # match a lowercase letter and save it to capture group 2
\2*      # match zero of more characters equals to the letter held by
         # capture group 2
(?=\2)   # positive lookahead asserts that following character equals the
         # contents of capture group 2
```

Note that `(?<!\S)` could replaced with `(?<=^|\s)` and `(?!\S)` replaced with `(?=\s|$)`, but I understand what I have is the more efficient of the alternatives.

You could also hover the cursor over each part of the regex at the regex101.com link to obtain an explanation of its function.

---

If, for example, the string were

```
"aaa abbb bba abbba ababbbab"
      ^^  ^    ^^      ^^
```

`"aaa"` would match `(?<!\S)([a-z])\1*(?!\S)` but then `\K` would cause those three characters to be discarded from the match that is returned, and would reset the start of the match to the location immediately before the space that follows `"aaa"`. `|` terminates that (zero-width) match which therefore is replaced with an empty string, resulting in no change to that part of the string.

Each of the following strings marked above with a caret (`^`) is matched by the second part of the alternation (`([a-z])\2*(?=\2)`) and therefore is replaced with an empty string.

Comment: Amazing. Really amazing explanation! Thank you so much, I with I could give you a hug! With PHP the regex was set to this `/(?<![^ ])([a-z])\\1*(?![^ ])\K|([a-z])(?=\\2)/` and it worked perfectly. For some reason I didnt need to use `(?<=^|\s)` at the beginning, just using `(?<![^ ])` worked perfectly (same fo the end, no need to use `$`)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution, as I thought there ought to be (making use of the "best regex trick ever" (https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html):

```
\b(?<whole_word>[a-z])\k{whole_word}++\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<not_whole_word>[a-z])\k{not_whole_word}++
```

which is the exact same (but less compact than what @Wiktor Stribiżew commented):

```
\b([a-z])\1+\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([a-z])\2+
```

and replace with:

```
$not_whole_word
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/pa0GjG/1

---

Explaination:

- `\b` if you find a whole word, ie. a word boundary
- `(?<whole_word>[a-z])\k{whole_word}++` followed by a character that makes up the whole word until the
- `\b` end of the word
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` then not match

  - `|` in every other case
- `(?<not_whole_word>[a-z])` match a character that is
- `\k{not_whole_word}++` repeated

---

OLD IDEA

---

You could use:

```
(?:(\b)|\B)(?!\k{char})(?<anything>.)(?<char>[a-z])\k{char}++(?(1)\B)
```

and replace with

```
$anything$char
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/yCNKY1/1

I guess there is a more obvious answer but this should work also.

---

- `(?:(\b)|\B)` check, whether you are at the beginning of a word or not. If so group 1 will be set.

  - `(?!\k{char})` check that the character of interest is not preceeded by itself
  - `(?<anything>.)` i.e. it must be preceeded by anything other

    - `(?<char>[a-z])` match the character
    - `\k{char}++` match all number of repetitions and do not give them up
- `(?(1)\B)` ensure, that if the start of the match was the start of a word, you are now not at the end -> you cannot match a complete word.

Comment: `\b([a-z])\1+\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([a-z])\2+` will do and is just shorter :)

Comment: If you post an answer and then get a better idea by all means edit your answer to present the new and improved version but why keep the old, inferior solution? It just muddles your answer (except when the two solutions are both good, in which you case you can say you are presenting two solutions). Nor is there a reason to say you've changed your answer. Just rewrite it as if starting from afresh. Write answers like you would write an article; readers don't want to see earlier drafts as part of the finished piece.

Comment: If a reader suggests an improvement in a comment there is no point to reproducing it in your answer. You are free, however, to edit your answer to use it, chucking what you had before (curious readers can always read earlier edits), in which case you should thank the reader and state that you've adopted the suggestion. Some people do that in the answer, others in a comment. I favour the latter, to keep the answer clean. Sometimes you'll find that the person making the helpful comment will then delete their comment, having no interest in taking credit for it.

Comment: what is SKIP and FAIL in the regex? I tried your regex with PHP and it does not work... I think skip/fail has something to do with it.

Comment: SKIP FAIL basically discards everythig that was matches previously; similar to \K. See https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail for more details. See https://regex101.com/r/Z1u6UR/latest to see the difference: \K "just" Keeps parts out of the match (still capturing `a` in the example), while skip fail makes the expression fail; in my example `a` is not captured to group 1.